# How can I assign shortcuts that activate the different installed Chrome Extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I have a few extensions (with their icons up on the right). I'd like to assign a shortcut for activating each one of them, i.e. a shortcut that simulates clicking the mouse on them.

One extension e.g. is a dictionary and it would be more than useful to be able to open it without tinkering with the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a way to do this in `chrome://extensions` if you go to the bottom of the page and find "Configure commands" link.

[image]

Comment: This option appears to be missing as of 28.0.1500.95 (stable).  It's been renamed "Keyboard Shortcuts" and it doesn't offer a complete list of all my extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I also am wondering about how to do this, and here is the possible solution suggested by Misha Kupriyanov:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/108214193841489989707/posts/2YBaEqRsCPw

> You can take the **Quick Disable Chrome** extension by +Paul Kinlan (you can find the source on github)
>
> It uses the **chrome.management API** http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html
>
> and now you can write your own pageAction extension ;) = include on each page your JavaScript for catching keyboard events and triggering enable/disable events via chrome.management API
>
> Also check out the **Vimium** (also open source) by Ilya Sukhar (i am not sure its his account)

Answer (score 1):

Try Autohot, it's a free tool that makes it easy to automate that kind of things, easiest would be:

1. wait for your "keyboard shortcut" to be fired
2. check that google chrome is the active window
3. click on the fixed mouse coordinate to activate the extension